# after msgget() , cout or printf are not working

Tags: c++

After using msgget() system call to create a msgQ  im not able to use cout or printf.

Below is my code trying to receive from a message Queue. 
The "printf" at line 28 does not print anything. But it works fine if i add one more "cout" or "printf" statement(say at line 29).Please let me know for any flaws in my code.

```
  1 #include<sys/errno.h>
  2 #include<sys/wait.h>
  3 #include<sys/ipc.h>
  4 #include<stdio.h>
  5 #include<iostream.h>
  6 #include<sys/msg.h>
  7 #include<sys/types.h>
  8
  9 struct messgQ
 10 {
 11         char text[1024];
 12         long int mtype;
 13 };
 14
 15
 16 int main()
 17 {
 18         struct messgQ R;
 19
 20         R.mtype=1;
 21
 22         int qid=0;
 23         qid=msgget((key_t)1234,0766|IPC_CREAT);
 24         cout<<"\n 1 MsgQ created with id ="<<qid;
 25
 26         if( qid > 0 )
 27         {
 28                 printf("\n  MsgQ created with id =%d",qid);
 29         }
 30
 31         int rc=0,run=1;
 32         while( run )
 33         {
 34                 memset(R.text,0x00,sizeof(R.text));
 35                 msgrcv(qid,&R,sizeof(R.text),1,0);
 36                 cout<<"\n Recvd:"<<R.text;
 37                 if( !strncmp(R.text,"bye",3) )
 38                 {
 39                         cout<<"\n Exiting";
 40                         run=0;
 41                 }
 42         }
 43                 rc=msgctl(qid,IPC_RMID,NULL);
 44                 if (rc < 0)
 45                 perror(strerror(errno));
 46 }
```

Comment: Is `qid` you're getting back from `msgget()` actually greater than zero?  Because if it isn't, the `printf()` wouldn't be called (and you'd need to look at `errno` to see why `msgget()` failed).

Answer (score 0):

The msgget documentation says

> RETURN VALUE
>          If successful, the return value will be the message queue identifier (a nonnegative integer), otherwise -1 with errno indicating the error.

So your check on line 26 is flawed, it should be:

```
if( qid >= 0 )
```

Regarding your output, stdout is normally line buffered when you print to a terminal. That means output isn't actually written out until you write a newline. So don't start your lines with a newline, but end with one instead.

```
printf("  MsgQ created with id =%d\n",qid);
cout<<"Recvd:"<<R.text << '\n';
cout<<"Exiting\n";
```

Alternatively, force the flushing by doing

```
cout.flush();
```

Or if you're using the C stdio functions such as printf, flush it with

```
fflush(stdout);
```